# how to make splash screen at API 33 android

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

Splash screen crushing app

I don´t know how to do a splash screen right now. I saw some tutorials of the api to do a splah screen and my activity crush always to add the theme. The app crush after run the splash screen correctly. This code its my theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.BookTFGNormal.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" tools:targetApi="s">@drawable/icon_book</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.SplashScreen </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I add the theme at my MainActivity since AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BookTFGNormal.MySplash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And I add this code at MainActivity:

> installSplashScreen()

At the tutorials; they add:

> setContent{}
> but I receive an error at setContent{} and I added to gradle implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'

Comment: Hi Simon,  first, you need to learn how the splash activity works on new Android API levels. You can always refer to the official Android page. Here you can refer to [Splash screen activity](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate)

Comment: Here's a video on the Android 12 splash screen you can watch: https://youtu.be/Loo4i5IrZ4Y. Also how to do it for older android versions: https://youtu.be/rIHArmoq9f8

Comment: I saw that tutorials xD. Its the same code that i used

Comment: could be cause the version of the android studio (and the compilesdkversion, etc... that generate with the project)?